# Error 4 Argument 5: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to 'string'

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building a winform application, and when I double-click on a button to add code I get the following errors:

1.

> Error 4 Argument 5: cannot convert from
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to 'string'

2.

> Error 3 The best overloaded method match for
>   'HRM.DAO.BaoHiem.themBH(string, string, string, string, string,
>   string)' has some invalid arguments

**Here is the code:**

```
private void btThem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    string MaNV = this.txtMaNV.ToString();
    string LoaiBH = this.cbLoai.ToString();
    string SoThe = this.txtSo.ToString();
    string NgayCap = this.dtpNgayCap.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    string NgayHH = this.dtpNgayCap.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");            
    string NoiCap = this.txtNoiCap.ToString();
    bh.themBH(MaNV, LoaiBH, SoThe, NgayCap, NgayHetHan, NoiCap);                       
}

// I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and MS SQL Server 2008

// This method is in another class, which is called from a button_Click event

public void themBH(string manv, string loaiBH, string sothe, 
    string ngaycap, string ngayhethan, string noicap)
{
    string sql = "Insert into [HRM].[dbo].[BaoHiem] values" + "(N'" + manv + "',N'" + 
        loaiBH + "',N'" + sothe + "',N'" + ngaycap + "',N'" + ngayhethan + "',N" + 
        "'" + noicap + "')";

    da.executeNonQuery(sql);
}
```

Comment: This: `string MaNV = this.txtMaNV.ToString();`, for example, should probably be `string MaNV = this.txtMaNV.Text.ToString();`, if `txtMaNV` is a control. The same for the others, if those are all controls. You could specify what are those *things* you are trying to pass to the method.

Comment: You're declaring `NgayHH`, but passing `NgayHetHan` as a parameter. Is this correct?

Comment: First, never concat SQL queries like that; always use DB Parameters.  But, if the data starts in a DGC, why extract it?  If it is bound data, you can update the DB with one statement and a DataAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems, as one of your objects is an DataGridViewTextBoxColumn what you can't transform to a string. Check out all objects - I assume that you hat to ad some .value or similar.
I further assume, that the second error is a follow up of the first (you try to pass am object as a string, what don't work).
I think, the second error will be solved, if you have fixed the first...

Comment: I try to use other DatetimePicker and convert it's value to string for "NgayHH", so that work and does'nt have any error. 
Following your idea, the second error is solved after i have fixed the first.